# How to dynamically set md-min-date/md-max-date of Angular Material md-datepicker directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I'm trying to walk thru month intervals with md-datepicker, therefore I created this codepen example for better demonstration:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygBGOg

When clicking 'PREV' button start interval seems not to be validated properly, when 'NEXT', closing interval respectively.

I tried to use vm.dateTo and vm.dateFrom in md-max-date/md-min-date

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="vm.dateFrom" md-max-date="vm.dateTo"></md-datepicker>
```

but it was the same like with using watchers

```
$scope.$watch('vm.dateFrom', function(v){
    vm.minDate = v;
});
```

datepickers were not validated properly.

Any ideas how could I achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2128200.aspx?Dynamically%20set%20minDate%20and%20maxDate%20on%20date%20picker%20angular%20js%20material) may provide the answer for this.

It basically has a `ng-change` handler that will reset the model property bound to the `md-min-date` which will immediately be reflected in the datepicker.